# vibrator in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, vibration

I want to use the vibration alert for the accelerometer action in an app using the Corona SDK.
Can any one give me some clue for this. I have tried searching for this in the internet but not found any useful clues.

Thanks in advance.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually super easy, put this line in;
system.vibrate()

That's all it takes. (I think it plays a beep sound on the simulator but nothing visual, so turn your sound up a bit while testing - or better yet build it. I used it in a test app 2 days ago.)